# localhost = HTTP Error 404

Tags: windows, iis

I have installed Windows 7 freshly in VMware as Homegroup. Turned off Firewall , no Antivirus installed yet, windows Defender turned off.
yet  localhost does not show in browser. Instead it shows 'HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found'.
I have enabled the 'Windows Features' 
   IIS / Web Management console and ISAPI Extensions , ISAPI Filters
I have checked that IIS is working because if I stop IIS it says 'This Site can's be reached'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had not marked the upper level boxes in Windows Features eg: IIS line on LHS box to be clicked into.
now it is fine

Comment: Can you give exact details of what you did and where.

Comment: @DovMiller search for Windows features on the start menu(Or access it through Control Panel). Under 'Internet Information Services' open 'Web Management Tools' you'll see IIS over there.